# Why can't you use " ' " on a numeric value in a table?

Tags: sql, oracle-apex

For an example, I wanted to search all employees in department 20. Why do I have to list is as the first one versus the second one. Does `'` only apply to data that is in words?

```
Select * from emp 
Where dept = 20
```

versus

```
Select * from emp
Where dept = '20'
```

Comment: `20` is a number, `'20'` is a string (character) value. You shouldn't compare apples to oranges

Comment: The documentation has [a section about literals](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Literals.html#GUID-192417E8-A79D-4A1D-9879-68272D925707), where you can see the difference between text (like `'20'`) and numeric (like `20`) literals. You can also read about [data conversion](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Data-Type-Comparison-Rules.html#GUID-6DB331B5-0F34-4215-9A20-16AEA9D7FF4B).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is about datatype.

- if `dept` column's datatype is `NUMBER`, you'd use `where dept = 20`
- if it is a string (one of `CHAR` datatypes; `VARCHAR2` being the most common), then you'd enclose value into single quotes: `where dept = '20'`

Oracle will try (and sometimes succeed) to implicitly convert one datatype to another. So, if `dept` column was a `varchar2` and you used `where dept = 20`, it *might* work. But, if there were `dept` values that aren't numerics but contain *letters* (e.g. departments whose values were `2A` or `CT`), then you might expect problems.

For example:

```
SQL> create table temp (dept varchar2(2));

Table created.
```

Insert works because of implicit conversion of `20` into a string:

```
SQL> insert into temp values (20);

1 row created.
```

Select also works:

```
SQL> select * from temp where dept = 20;

DE
--
20
```

This is, though, how you should be using it:

```
SQL> select * from temp where dept = '20';

DE
--
20
```

But, if not all values in a table are *numerics* (although stored into `varchar2` datatype column) ...

```
SQL> insert into temp values ('2A');

1 row created.
```

... then implicit conversion won't work any more:

```
SQL> select * from temp where dept = 20;
ERROR:
ORA-01722: invalid number



no rows selected
```

Enclosing the value into single quotes is the way to go:

```
SQL> select * from temp where dept = '20';

DE
--
20

SQL>
```

Comment: Thank you for the clarification! The teacher of the program did not go into depth but your explanation makes perfect sense.